# Check if value exists in next few rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df like :

```
df <- tibble(a = seq(ymd('2020-01-01'), ymd('2020-02-01'), "1 day"),
            b = sample(0:1, 32, prob = c(0.9, 0.1), replace = T))
```

I want to create a different df that has a flag called out, which is 1 if the value of b in that row or in the next 6 rows is 1 , otherwise it is zero

I have heard of lead and lag dplyr operators but not very sure how to use them.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(out = ifelse(1 %in% lead(b, 7), 1, 0))
```

With zoo solution the df looks like below which is not what I want because here the first 1 in `b` occurs at 2020-01-02 so the first row of `out` before it should have 1 (because it occurs either on that row of b or on the next 6 rows of b.) Similarly rows 3 to 5 should not be 1 because there is no 1 in b either on those rows or 6 rows after them.

```
set.seed(70)
df <- tibble(a = seq(ymd('2020-01-01'), ymd('2020-02-01'), "1 day"),
            b = sample(0:1, 32, prob = c(0.9, 0.1), replace = T))

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(out = +(zoo::rollapplyr(b, width = 7, FUN = function(x) any(x == 1), partial = TRUE)))


            a   b   out expected_out
1   2020-01-01  0   0    1
2   2020-01-02  1   1    1
3   2020-01-03  0   1    0
4   2020-01-04  0   1    0
5   2020-01-05  0   1    0
6   2020-01-06  0   1    1
7   2020-01-07  0   1    1
8   2020-01-08  0   1    1
9   2020-01-09  0   0    1
10  2020-01-10  0   0    1
11  2020-01-11  0   0    1
12  2020-01-12  1   1    1
13  2020-01-13  0   1    0
14  2020-01-14  0   1    0
15  2020-01-15  0   1    0
16  2020-01-16  0   1    0
17  2020-01-17  0   1    0
18  2020-01-18  0   1    0
19  2020-01-19  0   0    0
20  2020-01-20  0   0    0
21  2020-01-21  0   0    1
22  2020-01-22  0   0    1
23  2020-01-23  0   0    1
24  2020-01-24  0   0    1
25  2020-01-25  0   0    1
26  2020-01-26  0   0    1
27  2020-01-27  1   1    1
28  2020-01-28  0   1    0
29  2020-01-29  0   1    0
30  2020-01-30  0   1    0
31  2020-01-31  0   1    0
32  2020-02-01  0   1    0
```

Comment: can you sharre with a `set.seed` as I can't reproduce the exact data

Comment: Thanks akrun. Added the edits.

Comment: would you be able to update with the expected column as well so that I can  crosscheck

Comment: Sounds good. Done